# Cannot remotely connect to MySQL

Tags: networking, server, apache2, mysql

I've got a 3 servers & 1 Windows machine running in a LAN

```
HTTP server (Apache2, PHP5 & phpmyadmin) - 10.0.0.10
DNS - 10.0.0.1
MySQL - 10.0.0.40
Windows - 10.0.0.157
```

I've just installed a fresh copy of mysql on the mysql server. I've commented the bind-address out first off. I've given privileges by doing the following.

```
CREATE USER 'https'@'localuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE USER 'https'@'10.0.0.10' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'https'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'https'@'10.0.0.10';
```

However every time I try to connect to mysql via the http server the following happens

```
mysql -u https -p
enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)
```

When I try

```
mysql -h 10.0.0.40 -P 3306 -u https -p
```

I get a different error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'https'@'10.0.0.10' (Using password: Yes)`
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as far as I'm aware, I've done everything I need to configure? :(

In my mysql table for users I have the following

```
user  | host  
https  %
https   10.0.0.10
sqlserver   127.0.0.1
sqlserver ::1
debian-sys-maint  localhost
https    localhost
sqlserver    localhost
sqlserver    raspberrypi
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please? I've searched around and everything I see just points towards commenting the bind address line out.

*Edit* I can't even log in using locally using any user apart from `sqlserver` which was the root account that has been renamed. I've tried adding new accounts and logging in as them locally, still the same issue!

Comment: You should not comment out the bind address line (in /etc/my.cnf). Instead, you should point it to the server's IP address, i.e. 10.0.0.40, and restart MySQL.

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow and post the results

Comment: Tried this and i now get `error 1130 (hy000): host '10.0.0.10' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server` when trying `mysql -h 10.0.0.40 -u https -p` and with `mysql -u https -p` i get `error 2002 (hy000): can't connect to local mysql server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)`

Comment: I did `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘https’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’ WITH GRANT OPTION;` and `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘https’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’ WITH GRANT OPTION;` and I can at least login locally to mysql, still can't connect remotely though :-(

Comment: I tell a lie! I can connect using `mysql -h 10.0.0.40 -u https -p` fine. However using `mysql -u https -p` i still get the `error 2002`. But I don't care, it works! I can only assume I should have done `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘https’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’ WITH GRANT OPTION;` and was missing the `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` which has caused it to mess up.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question which Jos partly answered.

You should not comment out the bind address line (in `/etc/my.cnf`). Instead, you should point it to the server's IP address, i.e. `10.0.0.40`, and restart MySQL.

That combined with

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘https’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’ WITH GRANT OPTION;`
instead of
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'https'@'10.0.0.10';`
has fixed the issue. Hopefully this will help others having the same problem.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Is the service started? If not (or you're not sure), run:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: The server is already started thats correct

Answer (score 1):

if you execute

```
netstat -an | grep 3306
```

do you see an entry with LISTEN for port 3306?

Comment: I do this and nothing happens on my HTTP server

Comment: Now that I can connect I get `tcp   0   0   10.0.0.10:42605   10.0.0.40:3306   TIME_WAIT` I can only assume that this is now correct and working fine?